# Exit Method without ArgumentException

Tags: c#, exception, methods, arguments

i have a Cancel button on a Progressbar, which is used to Show the Progress of Uploading e-Mails,
now i want this button to Exit the method which Uploads e-Mails.
My plan, once the button gets pressed, make bool cancelUpload true.
i have been unlucky to exit the method with the use of break or simply through an if Statement.
but now i found online that i could throw an Argument Exception,
which i implemented as follows:

```
if (cancelUpload)
{
     throw new ArgumentException("SomeText");
}
```

but the Problem i have with this, is that once the User clicks on Cancel, he gets an Exception, which Looks like an Error or something went wrong, is there a way to get out of the method, without it looking as though something went wrong?(similiar to ArgumentException)
Thanks a lot in Advance!

Edit: The Method (void Method) is to big to be shown,
but when i tried to return;, i got an  Error in Visual Studio saying:
**TargetInvocationException was unhandled** Exception has been thrown by the target of invocation

Comment: Please show more context. It's unclear why you are not simply returning from the method with a `return`.

Comment: hey @DanielHilgarth please read the Edit

Comment: @gbbb There will be an `InnerException` you can check..

Comment: The `TargetInvocationException` is unrelated to the use of `return;`. Using `return;` is the correct way to do it. You better try to figure out where that exception comes from. Hint: Look at the InnerException, until you get one that is not a `TargetInvocationException`. This will help you figure out the real problem.

Comment: hi there, thanks for the replies,
but i don't seem to be able to find InnerException,
is it available in C# ?

Comment: @gbbb: Sure. It's a property on every exception.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: well i tried
if (cancelUpload)
{ throw new Innerexception} but it won't appear

Comment: @gbbb: ??? On the `TargetInvocationException` there is a property named `InnerException`. That's what you should check.